# Mac Monaco/Menlo font is too thin in my terminal/ide

Tags: macos, terminal, fonts

I am using the Monaco/Menlo font (15px) with iterm 2 and Atom IDE, but my font for some reason is too thin.

How I can make the font bolder as shown below?

Like this:

[image: like this]

Not like this:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Depending on the version of iTerm2 you're using (and possibly your display) this could be due to thin strokes for anti-aliased text.

You can change this setting from `iTerm > Preferences > Profiles > (some profile) > Text (tab)` or from a similar panel while editing the current session.

Look for **Use thin strokes for anti-aliased text** and change it to "always" for lighter text, "never" for heavier text or "on retina displays" for lighter text on retina displays.

Comment: Worth mentioning that I just upgraded to iTerm2 Build 3.0.0 and things felt much thinner than I was used to. It might not be typographically correct but I prefer slightly heaver type with light-on-dark themes like the Solarized Dark theme I'm using.

Comment: Just migrated to Retina display from older mac book. The annoying part is that bold letters looks almost exactly the same as regular. Even though Monako does not have bold font, on my old macbook I could see the distinct difference.

Comment: tbh, thinner fonts are much easier on eyes